# add a required field with php

Tags: php

I want to design a dynamic form using php. suppose i have created a text box using javascript as follow

```
var labels=new Array()
function add(type) {
     var element = document.createElement("input");
     var label=prompt("Enter the name for lable","");
     labels.push(label);
     document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML=document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML+label;

     element.setAttribute("type", type);
     element.setAttribute("name",label);


     var rohit = document.getElementById("raj");
    rohit.appendChild(element);

    document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML=document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML+"<br/>";

}
```

I want to make this field as a required field using php(it is required). what should i do for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want do do, but if you're using POST to send it to PHP then you can check if the value is empty like this

```
<?php 

if(empty($_POST['value_name']))
{
      echo 'value is required';
}
else
{
      // OK 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In html5 you can set a `required` attribute.

```
element.setAttribute("required", "required");
```

If you want to use PHP, as mentioned in the question, that would happen on the server side. You have to validate the request received by a php script & check whether it is empty or not.